# Is it possible for multisig wallets to have trusted addresses? (Dynamic amount of permissions required)

Tags: transactions, wallet, multi-signature, trust

I've been wondering if it is by design possible to have a multi-signature wallet which has a set of trusted addresses which require less signatures.

Let's say I have a 3-of-5 wallet, but all address holders agree there is a certain address which is trusted and should only require 2-of-5 or even 1-of-5 signatures.

Is it possible to implement such a wallet? If so, do any mainstream wallets currently have this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a wallet function. This can be done with m-of-n multisig script.

for example Alice, Bob, Charley, David and Eva want to have 3-of-5 multisig address, but David is `manager` and it is enough to have 2 signatures for spending if one signer is David. Eva is `bigboss` and can spend funds alone.

So, the redeem script can be

```
OP_3 pubA pubB pubC pubD OP_DUP pubE OP_DUP OP_DUP OP_8 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```